# setSiteRestriction not working on a specific website

Tags: google-api

On my search I want to filter results to my website, I tried the following:

```
webSearch.setSiteRestriction("orkutmanager.net");
```

But it doesn't work... If I set it to `amazon.com`

```
webSearch.setSiteRestriction("amazon.com");
```

It works.

Searching on Google's main page it works normally, e.g. [`orkut site:orkutmanager.net`](http://www.google.com/search?q=orkut+site%3Aorkutmanager.net&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a)

Is it a bug? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a custom search and added the id instead of the url

```
webSearch.setSiteRestriction("017220008487069298117:xgy2xbuc2io");
```